# How do the Sanskrit epics mark a turning point to Hinduism?

Tags: mahabharata, vishnu, ramayana, pandavas

How do events in the epics relate to a gradual change in Hinduism, eg the game of dice, Yalsha's riddles, the war etc? 
Does it mark the introduction of buddhism at all?

Comment: In my opinion, the biggest change the epics brought, was the elevation of Vishnu and Shiva, as the great Gods of hinduism. Before that, Indra and Agni occupied the primary position.

Comment: The pancharatra philosophy which is discussd in MB was there before Vyasa written MB.And in pancharatra Vishu is considered as supreme ,so we can't say surely that epics only elevated ranks of both of these.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto What I mentioned is my opinion. I cannot post it as an answer.

Comment: If not Buddhism these events foreboded the onset of kali. Buddhism is basically an atheist religion that has shUnya & nAstikya as the base. Its core philosophy is antithesis of everything vedic. Since Hinduism is founded on the 4 Vedas any philosophy that is in the nature of opposing vedic principles is Asuric and therefore should be considered as due to the advent of kaliyuga. So the events in MBH like vastrAharaNa game of dice war etc are all a sequel to Kali and thereby a sequel to the advent of shramaNa & mahAshramaNa religions that's Jainism & buddhism.